# ipython-cypher %cypher magic broken in neo4j 3.0?

Tags: neo4j, ipython, cypher, ipython-magic

I am using jupyter notebook and ipython-cypher but since neo4J version 3.0 has a mandatory password change I seem not to be able to use the %cypher magic... (single % ... %%cypher works as I can pass the connection url on the first line)

```
results = %cypher MATCH (person:Person)-[:LIKES]->(drink:Drink) \
                  RETURN person.name AS name, drink.name AS drink

df = results.get_dataframe()

df
```

Obviously gives:

```
StatusException: Code [401]: Unauthorized. No permission -- see authorization schemes.
Authorization Required
```

So HOW do I pass the connection URL with the user/pwd combi in this case?
(%%cypher works ok)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works the same way like `%%`:

```
%load_ext cypher

result = %cypher http://neo4j:password@localhost:7874/db/data MATCH (a) RETURN a LIMIT 5

print(result)
```

I tried it with Python 3.5, ipython-cypher 0.2.4 and neo4j 3.1.

However, the requirements in the docs do not mention neo4j 3.x: http://ipython-cypher.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#requirements

Comment: also adding a config option likeso works: `%config CypherMagic.uri='http://neo4j:snampook@localhost:7474/db/data/'`